# Cannot connect to couchbase server

Tags: java, couchbase, timeoutexception

I cannot connect to a couchbase server that runs on a different computer of the same local network.

The machine has the IP address 192.168.1.150. I use the [official hello-couchbase tutorial](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/java-2.1/hello-couchbase.html) for the Java SDK. Thus, my code looks like this:

```java
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create("192.168.1.150");
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket();
```

The second line triggers:

```
 com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /192.168.1.150:11210
```

Is there any way to narrow down the reason for the connection failure? The webclient on localhost:8091 (in a browser of the remote machine)  tells me that the server is running.

Comment: can it be, that you have to take the right port to get connection?

Comment: in Java SDK 2.x, you only specify the ip so that's not a problem of port missing from the connection String. however, you say that you use the webclient on `localhost:8091`? that would mean the server is actually running on the machine that runs the code, wouldn't it? if not (you opened a browser on the remote machine), then can you actually access `192.168.1.150:8091` in the browser/curl from the machine that runs the java code?

Comment: @SimonBaslé You are completely right with your assumption. The execution just yields another timeout error. Do you know which port is actually used for the Java SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with a firewall.  Can you telnet from your client machine to the Couchbase server on port 11210?  From a command prompt, type telnet 192.168.1.150 11210

If you see a blinking cursor, the test succeeded and the firewall is likely not a problem.  You may need to install a telnet client if it isn't already available.  Windows Telnet installation: http://www.wikihow.com/Activate-Telnet-in-Windows-7

Comment: Ok I just adapted the firewall rules. Now, timeout exceptions are not the problem, any more. However, I get new errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29348577/couchbase-connection-refused